# Correct way to calculate Gas Price and Gas Limit using offline mode in ethereumj

Tags: ethereumj

Please help me to understand the correct way to compute `Gas Price` and `Gas Limit` using `offline` mode in `ethereumj`.

I have been using EtherScan's API `eth_gasPrice` and `eth_estimateGas` as of now. Just wanted to understand if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer: [how to estimate gas cost?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27452/how-to-estimate-gas-cost)

But I find that it is difficult to follow.

What I did was I look at my transaction receipt after a successful transaction. There is a gasUsed field inside. And it gives a good estimate about the gasPrice, inside my private node.

Refer to my questions here. [Question about Gas and Gas Price](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52973/question-about-gas-and-gas-price)

I also hope someone can gives a better answer :(