# Estimate Gas Cost before SendTransaction

Tags: solidity, gas, metamask, javascript, gas-estimate

How meta estimating gas cost before broadcasting.

How can I calculate gas cost for `myfunc()` in web3js?

```
function myfunc(){
   require(msg.sender == owner)
   ...
}

await contractInstance.myfunc.sendTransaction(); //it sends the transaction and wastes the gas if `myfunc` will fail.
```

Is there any best way to know gas cost before call solidity `myfunc()`, its saves gas for me ? (Similar like metamask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web3 has an [estimateGas](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas) method you can use to estimate the gas required for the transaction.  You can use it for contract methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is way but not that much accurate. Just add 10 or 20% extra gas.

```
contractInstance.method.estimateGas(ARGS...);
```

Please have a look below link

[how to estimate gas cost?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27452/how-to-estimate-gas-cost)

Comment: How do you add 10 - 20%?