# Truffle Console: Estimate Gas Cost of a function

Tags: truffle-console

I checked the following link:
[how to estimate gas cost?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27452/how-to-estimate-gas-cost)

My contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract TransferGC{
   uint public testVal = 97 ether;
   function testFunc(address payable addr) public returns (uint) {
      addr.transfer(testVal);
      return testVal;
   }
   function deposit() payable public{}
}
```

I did the following:

```
TGC = await TransferGC.at('0xE4F90Ef2e5815cf24eea956b1f5781601859cb90')
truffle(development)> await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
'20000000000'
await TGC.testFunc('0x3e1D6ef576d19A6D28f3755acDb754E37aFe6E4A').estimateGas(1)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Thrown: TypeError: TGC.testFunc(...).estimateGas is not a function

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the syntax of this line:

```
await TGC.testFunc('0x3e1D6ef576d19A6D28f3755acDb754E37aFe6E4A').estimateGas(1)
```

into:

```
await TGC.testFunc.estimateGas('0x3e1D6ef576d19A6D28f3755acDb754E37aFe6E4A')
```

Because the arguments should go within the `estimateGas` method. For more information about the `estimateGas` method, check the [documentation](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#special-methods-on-truffle-contract-objects) on truffle.