# Question about Gas and Gas Price

Tags: gas-price, gas-estimate

In my transaction: **gasPrice: 210000**

```
blockHash: "0x69bd71736f2a5d2c83919a0de81a7de0b6b690bb6bdda3acff254d5c68f634bc",
blockNumber: 3178,
from: "0xc8caa71c16299b40b8579742a27ee53162886040",
gas: 2100000000,
gasPrice: 210000,
```

And the receipt: **gasUsed: 72769**

```
blockHash: "0x69bd71736f2a5d2c83919a0de81a7de0b6b690bb6bdda3acff254d5c68f634bc",
blockNumber: 3178,
contractAddress: null,
cumulativeGasUsed: 72769,
from: "0xc8caa71c16299b40b8579742a27ee53162886040",
gasUsed: 72769,
```

Is that means my total gas consumed = 72769 x 210000 = 15281490000 or 15GWei?

Can I safely assume **gasUsed** will remains the same if the execution condition (i.e. input parameters) remain the same? Even when I move my code from test node to the main ETH?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I safely assume gasUsed will remains the same if the execution
>   condition

No. The gas may vary even calling the sane function. See [Why transaction cost for same function differs even though content of function is same?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26535/why-transaction-cost-for-same-function-differs-even-though-content-of-function-i) and [this.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45923/will-same-contract-consume-different-gas-in-different-network)

Also`gasPrice` changes dynamically. So you can not always send static gas price (210000). Sending less gas can result into failing of tx and sending less gas price may take a lot of time to get mined.

The better option is to use `estimateGas` to check for gas of your transactions and `eth.gasPrice` to estimate gas.

You can increase gas to more what you estimated because extra gas is refuded.

Comment: I am asking about the **gasUsed** in the transactionReceipt but not about the gasPrice

Comment: gasUsed in tx receipt is the actual gas consumed. This also won't be constant. So may be this time gas consumed is `72769` but on subsequent calls this may vary.

Comment: I don't think so, since the gasUsed is lower than my gasPrice.

Comment: @sk The term `gasUsed` refers to an entirely different parameter than `gasPrice`. While `gasPrice` is the price in wei you will pay to the miner for each unit of gas consumed, `gasUsed` indicates how many gas units were actually consumed by the transaction. You are probably mistaking `gasPrice` for `gasLimit`, which indicates the highest allowable gas consumed on your transaction.

Comment: @Alex, if you read my original question carefully, I have never confused between gasPrice, gasLimit and gasUsed. It was Prashant

Comment: I was trying to explain more than what u asked, so that future peoples visiting this question may be benefited. And for your question, I already answered in first line. **NO**.